# Is using ads module in any content management system perilous?

Tags: cms, google-adsense

Is using ads module in any content management system to deliver Adsense ads perilous? It states that delivering Adsense ads through advanced scripts is prohibited.

Comment: Who or what is it?

Answer (score 1):

What they mean by delivering ads through advanced scripts is writing JavaScript or some other code that delivers the Adsense adverts. You could get really creative by writing JS code which hides the Adsense ads, or server side application (like a crawler) that could be used to trick Adsense into thinking you are serving ads.

Google will catch all of these Adsense hacking attempts and shut you down real quick.

As for using ads module in Wordpress or Joomla to simply place your Adsense code on different sections of your blog or site, or using a PHP include to put Adsense on a certian template is totally acceptable and usually how it is done.

Also, take a look at `buysellads.com` might do better for you than Adsense. Also look at `cj.com`.  Usually a good affiliate program pays a lot more than the pennies you might earn through Adsense.

Last, if your site is serious, or selling something, you probably should not put ads on it to begin with.  Unless if your site is in Korean at which point you can put 100 ads, and anime kittens all over it.